# CKEditor - add in custom attribute

Tags: ckeditor

In CKEditor I'm having issues adding some dataProcessor rules.

I have a custom plugin defined in ckeditor/plugsin/x
I have added the plugin name to config.js extraPlugins

My plugin looks like

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('x',   
  {    

    init:function(editor)
    { 
        editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
        {
            elements :
            {
                div : function( element )
                {
                    element.setAttribute("x","y");
                }
            }
        });

        editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules(
        {
            elements :
            {
                div : function( element )
                {
                    element.setAttribute("x","y");
                }
            }
        });

});
```

However it doesn't insert the attribute.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I have tried another plugin using the example code from http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials/Timestamp_Plugin and this also doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

`CKEDITOR.dataProcessor` works with [`CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element) instead of [`CKEDITOR.dom.element`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element). `CKEDITOR.htmlParser.element` is not a real DOM element but an abstract object to make parsing and filtering much easier. It has own set of methods and attributes.

Also note that `dataFilter` works on input data (what comes to the editor) while `htmlFilter` deals with output data (content produced by the editor).

You should also get used to [Allowed Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) because quite likely you need to configure it to have the editor working properly, i.e. `config.extraAllowedContent = 'div[x]'`.

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oleq/nbzrdsq2/).

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    extraAllowedContent: 'div',
    on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function() {
            this.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    div: function( el ) {
                        console.log( 'processing', el, 'in dataFilter' );
                        el.attributes.datafilter = 'x';
                    }
                }
            } );    

            this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    div: function( el ) {
                        console.log( 'processing', el, 'in htmlFilter' );
                        el.attributes.htmlfilter = 'y';
                    }
                }
            } );              
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: In your example all works fine, but in Drupal I have a trouble. For 
"span: function" 
it works well, but for 
"div: function"
it doesn't work. Maybe can be some restrictions? Or options which can be reason of this trouble? Thx

Comment: @Eugene Is `div` allowed in your editor (`CKEDITOR.instances.editor.filter.check( 'div' )`)?

Comment: Please check this one https://jsfiddle.net/nbzrdsq2/6/, it doesn't work with property contenteditable="false"

Comment: Seems I solved this problem https://jsfiddle.net/nbzrdsq2/8/ I've added option applyToAll: true